# How to get Value by Id from List in another Class

Tags: c#, list, getvalue

I have the following code strucutre:

I have a `Population` class that has a List with all `Humans` of the population.
The `population` class does also have a List with all existing `Genes`.

A `Gene` struct stores an Id and a Value (for simplicity just a simple string).

Now i want to pass the Id of the `Gene` that a `Human` has, and not the whole `Gene` struct because
multiple `Humans` could have the same `Gene` and that would be redundant.

Imagine there are 100 different `Genes` and the `Population` is has a size of 100 and a Human has 5 Genes.
Then i would have to store 100 * 100 * 5 `Genes` in total across all `Humans`.
But if i would have a List of all available `Genes`  stored in the `Population` and just pass the Id's of the `Genes` to the `Human`, then i would just need to store 100 Genes no matter how big the `Population` is and how many `Genes` a `Human` has.

But how do i retrieve the value of a `Gene` inside of a `Human` when the `Human` just has the Id?

```
internal class Population
    {
        List<Human> population = new List<Human>();

        List<Gene> Genes = new List<Gene>();

        public Population() 
        {
            CreateGenes(10);
            CreatePopulation(10);
        }

        private void CreateGenes(int GeneCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GeneCount; i++)
            {
                Genes.Add(new Gene() { Id = i, Value = "abc" });
            }
        }

        private void CreatePopulation(int populationCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < populationCount; i++)
            {
                population.Add(new Human() { GenID = Genes[i].Id });
            }
        }
    }

internal class Human
    {
        public int GenID;

        public string GeneValue()
        {
            // HOW DO I GET THE VALUE FROM THE LIST IN THE POPULATION?
        }
    }

public struct Gene
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Value;
    }
```

Comment: Populate a `Dictionary<int, Gene>` with your 100 gene instances (use the `Id` value as the key), then use that to look up the gene associated with a given id

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but how to i acces it from the Human Class when it is in the Population Class. Look at the `GeneValue()` Method... what do i put there

Comment: Either move the gene value resolution method to the `Population` class (the question only makes sense in the context of a population anyway, right?), or redesign the `Human` class to hold a reference to its associated `Population`

Comment: " or redesign the Human class to hold a reference to its associated Population"
Could you give a quick example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this will only work if Humans can access the Genes List. But id still recommend to store the Genes in the Humans, because Lists dont store the "Object" but a reference to that Object. Also your GenID in humans wont allow for a Human to have multiple Genes since you only have one ID. But Ill still try to do it along your lines
One little change to population

```cs
public class Population{

    public static List<Gene> Genes = new List<Gene>();
    ...
}
```

And now a change in your Human class

```cs
public string GeneValue()
{
    return Population.Genes.First(g =>g.Id == GenID).Value;
}
```

But do not overarching Lists like theese arent really good to do. It does make sense to have a List from where you can access all Genes, if needed, but id still reccommend to have a Genes List in the Humans.

Or if the GeneValue Method is called from Population you can just make the List a parameter:

```cs
public string GeneValue(List<Gene> genes)
{
    return genes.First(g =>g.Id == GenID).Value;
}
```

Comment: i gave the Human just 1 Id in this example for simplicity. In my main project the Human has a List of Ids for the Genes

The reason why i dont want to have all available genes in the Human is because multiple Humans could have the exact same gene and that would be redundant. I just want the Human to look up the value of the id of the gene that it has.

Comment: Well i meant to not put ALL genes in the human but just theirs. But this as I said my example still goes along your guidelines.

Comment: Ok i've got the Solution
Making the List of Genes in the Population static helped me! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`Human` instances could have the same reference to a given `Gene` instance : you don't duplicate the object, but only the reference. Actually, to duplicate an object in C#, you have to do it really explicitly.

So, you could replace the `Human.GenID` by `Human.HumanGene` :

```
internal class Human
{
    public Gene HumanGene;

    public string GeneValue()
    {
        return HumanGene.Value;
    }
}
```

And redefine your `CreatePopulation` method like this :

```
private void CreatePopulation(int populationCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < populationCount; i++)
    {
        population.Add(new Human() { HumanGene = Genes[i] });
    }
}
```